# Syntax highlighting in Jekyll based on YAML variable

Tags: syntax-highlighting, markdown, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

When writing markdown with code to be read by Jekyll, you can enable syntax highlighting with

```
{% highlight python %}
x = ('a', 1, False)
{% endhighlight %}
```

However, this becomes a bit verbose if you constantly switch between code and text. Is it possible to introduce a YAML variable in the header, like

```
---
layout: page
title: "Syntax highlighting"
tags : [python, jekyll]
language: python
---
```

so that every code block on this page will be highlighted like python, but only needs to be indented, and not fenced off?

Answer (score 3):

Fenced blocks
[were introduced](http://github.com/blog/832)
with Redcarpet 2. Jekyll
[now appears](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/commit/098da3d) to
support Redcarpet 2.

```
~~~ python
x = ('a', 1, False)
~~~
```

If you want it a little simpler you can make it
[a two-liner](http://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/pull/15), but that’s the best deal you’re going to get.

```
    x = ('a', 1, False)
{:.language-python}
```

Comment: I don't object to the `Liquid` syntax, I'm bothered by the fact that every one-liner of code turns into three lines. It clutters up the markdown sources.

Comment: Didn't even know about fenced blocks, I'm still using triple backticks. Cool.